# Facebook comments not showing in mobile

Tags: facebook, mobile

I have this website named 1FAKT and i have integrated Facebook comments on it. Strangely comments made in Facebook comments are visible in desktop template BUT are not showing in mobile template.

Example:
Post in desktop: [Desktopo Link](http://www.1fakt.com/2016/01/ja-kush-perfundon-ne-burg-nga-reforma.html)
Same post in mobile: [Mobile Link](http://www.1fakt.com/2016/01/ja-kush-perfundon-ne-burg-nga-reforma.html?m=1)

Mobile is default active in Facebook script. Then what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had a similar issue.  For me, this was due to css flex-box properties that I had assigned to div containing facebook comments plugin.  When I removed the styles for this div the plugin worked fine.  You may also want to try assigning data-mobile="false" property to your comments div.  See below for an example of code that worked for me.

```
<div style='text-align:center;'>
  <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://localhost:8000/es/comments" data-width="600" data-numposts="10" data-mobile:"false"></div>
</div>
```